# Serverless Framework The provided execution role does not have permissions to call SendMessage on SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am trying to create an AWS SQS queue using the serverless framwework,
But I am getting the following error on deploying the `severless.yaml`

```
The provided execution role does not have permissions to call SendMessage on SQS
```

The issue is the IAM role is created by serverless framework and I have no control of what permissions the framework adds to the role,
Ideally, if the function trigger is an SQS, or needs a DLQ configured,
I was hoping the framework would add Send and Receive message permissions to the role, but I guess it did not

**Serveless.yaml -**

```
service: dlq

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  profile: csStage
  region: ap-southeast-1

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

functions:
  dlqFunction:
    handler: handler.hello

    deadLetter:
      sqs: dl-queue
```

Answer (score 2):

You have complete control over the permissions added to that role. You can add an `iamRoleStatements` section to your serverless.yml file under `provider` that describes the permissions you wish to apply to the role applied to functions. It would look something like:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:sqs:region:accountid:queueid
```

You can find out more in the official documentation here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/#iam/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iamRoleStatements](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/) to give that permission to your Lambda function. The following template worked for me:

```
service: dlq

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  profile: csStage
  region: ap-southeast-1

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:SendMessage
      Resource: !GetAtt DLQ.Arn

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

functions:
  dlqFunction:
    handler: handler.hello

    deadLetter:
      targetArn:
        GetResourceArn: DLQ

resources:
    Resources:
      DLQ:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
        Properties:
          QueueName: dl-queue
```